# It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'

Tags: syntax, syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to write a code that calculate the size of a list.

Here is what I've done:

```
let rec l = function 
  | [] -> 0 
  | t::q -> 1 + l q


print_int(l ([1;2;3;4]))
```

The problem is that it's saying me :

```
It is applied to too many arguments; maybe you forgot a `;'.
```

When I put the double semicolon `;;` at the end of the definition of `l` it works well, yet I've read that `;;` is not useful at all if you are not coding in the REPL, so here I don't see why it's giving me this error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following

```
print_int(l [1;2;3;4])
```

is a toplevel expression. Such expression needs to be preceded by `;;`:

```
;; print_int(l [1;2;3;4])
```

Another option is to make this toplevel expression a binding with

```
let () = print_int(l [1;2;3;4])
```

Comment: Thank you! How do you actually now this is a toplevel expression ? Even if print_int has type unit we are in the obligation to use let () =... ?

Comment: Because for example when doing a pattern matching like : let rec print_l = function |[] -> print_int 0     so here I am not using the syntax let () = ... and directely using print_int and I have no mistake

Comment: You used "let" as in "let rec print_l".

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Ok, thank you ! So now let's say I want to use my print_l function , should I use : let () = print_l m or I should directly do : print_l m; ?

Comment: You can use either `let () = side_effect() in ...` or `side_effect(); ...` inside an expression.

Comment: Ok got it, so every expressions should be preceed by let

Comment: Must be preceed by let. It is not optional in the grammar. Only in the top level there is special handling to make testing expressions easier.

Comment: Ok, thank you for taking your time ! I think I understood !

Answer (score 1):

When parsing the code the parser advances until it hits `l q`. At this point there could be more arguments that should get applied to the function l. So the parser keeps going and the next thing it finds is the value print_int. Another argument to l. Which gives you your error.

The parser has no way of knowing that you had finished the code for the function l. In the top level the special token `;;` is used to tell the parser that the input is finished and it should evaluate the code now. After that it starts paring the remaining input again.

Now why doesn't compiled code also have the ';;' token?

Simply because its not needed. In compiled code the line `print_int(l [1;2;3;4])` is not valid input. That would be a statement you want to execute and functional languages have no such thing. Instead `print_int(l [1;2;3;4])` is an expression that returns a value, () in this case, and you have to tell the compiler what to do with that value. A `let () =` tells the compiler to match it against (). And the `let ...` also tells the compiler that the previous `let rec l ...` has finished. So no special `;;` token is needed.

Or think of it this way: In the top level there is an implicit `let _ =` if your input doesn't start with let. That way you can just type in some expression and see what it evaluates to without having to type `let _ =` every time. The ';;' token still means "evaluate now" though and is still needed.

Comment: Thank you for your answer It's much clear now. So whenever I have some function 'f', if I want to use f I have to use the syntax : let a = f ...; What's king of strange to me, is the fact that let a = ... is saying put in a the value of ..., so when I do something like let a = print_int 2; it should do nothing. So I don't understand why it actually evaluate the expression. In other langage like C, creating a function doesn't execute it

Comment: `let` does not create a function. It creates a value. Which means it evaluates the code. Now `let f x = ...` is syntactic sugar for `let f = function x -> ...` and evaluating the code `function x -> ...` returns a value that represents a function. The "function" delays the execution of the rest until you apply an argument to the function. You just don't see that you used "function" when you write `let f x = ...`.

Comment: Ok, so in Ocaml how do you store functions that you don't want them to be evaluated ? For example let x = print_int 2; will print 2, but if I just want to say, x is just a function such that whenever I call x it prints me the value 2.  Moreover if we have let x = print_int 2, then after x is evaluated what is in x ? Can I do smething like : let () = x and it will print the value 2 ?

Comment: You can use `()` as argument for functions too, like: `let print2 () = print_int 2`. Now print2 is a function taking an argument of type unit returning unit that will then print 2 as a side effect when called. Having an extra unit argument is a common occurance to delay evaluation of code. Often used in constructors where every call should return a fresh value.